# npm install work but jspm not

Tags: aurelia, npm-install, jspm

I'm working on an `Aurlia.io` project. Suddenly the jspm stopped working.
If I retry running the command `jspm install`, I get an error that a different package failed to load.

```
 warn Error on lookup for npm:babel-runtime
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.12.162:80
         at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
         at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
         at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)

err  Error looking up npm:babel-runtime.
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Problem solved! 
just go to edit system environment variables and add to new user variables
1.HTTP_PROXY=<your proxy shit>
2.HTTPS_PROXY=<your proxy shit with https>

Comment: You should add this as an official answer and mark the question as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

@Eliav Maman has the answer in his comment:

Problem solved! just go to edit system environment variables and add
to new user variables 1.HTTP_PROXY= your proxy 
2.HTTPS_PROXY=your proxy with https

I'm trying to get this question marked as answered.